# How to upload image(Base64 String) to the server from Android with NodeJS as a back end?

Tags: android, node.js, api, image-uploading, retrofit2

I am using Node js to upload an image from Android Application. The results are very unpredictable. Sometimes the uploads are a success and sometimes it's a fail. I am using Retrofit on the client side to send data to the server API, which consists of two fields 1) Base64 String and 2) Image name. On the server side I am using this piece of code

```
app.post("/api/image", function (req, res) {
    var image = req.body.image;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var response = {};

    fs.writeFile(path, new Buffer(image, "base64"), function (err) {
        response.message = "success";
        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

At times I get the success message and most of the times its a failure. 

What could be the issue? I was using PHP before I jumped ship to Node Js, and the same client code was successful on PHP but fails in Node js.
Note: I am using AWS.

Comment: Do you get an *error* when the upload fails ?

Comment: Why base64-encode the image when you could just send the raw image data instead, especially since it appears you may already be using multipart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to find where error occurs: before writeFile call or before middleware call. Also it's good to enhance your question with detailes: what actually happens and where process fails, does it create file or not, etc.

There could be several issues:

- Body is too big (100K for body-parser if I'm right).
- Body is corrupted (use md5 hash to ensure).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pasha is right. The body was too big as certain images were bigger than others so I followed this code and solved my problem.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true,parameterLimit:50000}));
```